# SimpleXml not parsing when child has a namespace

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I'm working with a third party web service which returns an xml format with something like this

```
<s:root xmlns:s="http://someradomurl.com">
    <s:body>
        <title>Hello World</title>
        <content>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolorum quasi voluptate iste, ea cumque at aut accusantium sequi tempore in, consectetur sapiente quibusdam eius vel ex labore itaque ipsum nulla.</content>
    </s:body>
</s:root>
```

Now, the `SimpleXml` element can't seem to parse this but when I remove the prefix from `s:body`, the attributes get assigned accordingly.

Is there any way for the XML to be parsed without having to edit the response?

Comment: You need to register XPath Namespace.  That should allow you to get the response without having to edit the document.

Comment: Thanks! I had a mistake in predicting it's behaviour and thought it would assign it to the root variable.